# embeds[0].description: This field is required

Tags: discord.js

I am using the lastest version of discord.js v13 and the latest version of node and every single package. I am getting the following error and here is the code. Please help.

**Error**

```
embeds[0].description: This field is required
```

**Code**

```
    const exampleEmbed =
        ({
            embeds: [new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#1a038a')
                .setTitle('Proxy')
                .setDescription('Proxy Help Embed')
                .addFields(
                    { name: 'Bot', value: '`ping`, `invite`', inline: false },
                )
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter('TEST')
                .setImage('IMAGE')
                .setURL('URL')]
        })
    return message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });

}
```

Here is the full error of this code

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exampleEmbed` variable is an object with the property `embeds` which is an array, therefore you must do:

```js
return message.channel.send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed.embeds[0]] });
```

To access the first item in the `embeds` property of the `exampleEmbed` variable.

The error:

```js
embeds[0].description: This field is required
```

Says that the first embed of the `embeds` array in the `MessagePayload` doesn't have a description, hinting the requested location in the `exampleEmbed` variable doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay I will try this right now then inform you the results.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: Using the exact code you provided and only changing the single line I specified it worked just fine for me. Maybe that error came form a different point of origin.

Comment: But it shows the error came from there.